# WebSocket send data to server on initial request

Tags: node.js, websocket, request

So like the title is saying at the first request the client does, i want to send the client id to the server.

`var userId = "userId"; var ws = new WebSocket("wss://serveradress?clientId")`

Is there anyway to pass the data on the initial request via query string or something.

Appreciate every idea, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/onopen) you can call the websocket onopen method. Then in the callback use the websocket send method to send data

```
websocket.onopen = function() {
   websocket.send(your data)
}
```

To accept the incoming message server side just accept the request. This is assuming you are using [websocket-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket)

```
ws.on('request', (request) => {
  const conn = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin)
  conn.on('message', (message) => {
     console.log(message)
  })
})
```

If you are using [this package](https://github.com/websockets/ws) then just listen for the 'message' event.

```
ws.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log(message)
})
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can i handle the data on the server-site?

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you are using a different package for websockets server side this will not work. I would advise using https://github.com/websockets/ws

Comment: Nice it seems to work, but the output now is {type:'utf8', utf8Data:'userId'}. How can i extract only the userid to pass it into a variable??

Comment: I would highly suggest reading that link I posted. And also using the other library I mention. However as per the docs you would access it by message.utf8Data